Не работает бот
После установки библиотек то ли несовместимых, то ли более новых перестал запускаться бот, хотя до этого работал исправно. Вот аутпут с терминала

что помешало вам добавить ошибку текстом, а не картинкой?

это скрин vnc с браузера

втупую начал сравнивать версии библиотек на основной машине и на виртуальной, поставил более старые версии и бот заработал. вероятнее всего дело было в более новой версии py-cord, с версией 2.4.1 всё норм
